# Add incremented number in XML array using datawave 2.0 mule4?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

How can I add an incremented number in XML array using datawave 2.0 in mule4?

Example:

```
<Employees>    
    <Employee>    
        <Attribute Name="IncrementValue"></Attribute>    
    </Employee>    
    <Employee>    
        <Attribute Name="IncrementValue"></Attribute>    
    </Employee>    
<Employees>
```

Above example update IncrementValue with a sequence number. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

DataWeave is a functional language. It doesn't have a counter but you may use the index of the mapObject() function for this ejemplo:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
Employees: payload.Employees mapObject((value1, key1, index1) ->
    Employee: value1 mapObject ((value2, key2, index2) -> (key2): index1) 
)
```

Output for the input in the description:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Attribute Name="IncrementValue">0</Attribute>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Attribute Name="IncrementValue">1</Attribute>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Index starts from 0. If you want to start from 1 you could just add 1: `index + 1`

Comment: How can i use variable to increment value?

Comment: Please clarify why using the index does not answer the original question. I see that you created a new question for not using the index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145117/how-can-i-increment-variable-value-inside-function-mapobject-datawave-2-0