# How can i increment variable value inside function mapobject datawave 2.0?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

How can i increment variable value inside mapobject(I do not want to use index) in mule4 datawave2.0?
My Code:

```
"Employees":{(inputData.*Employees.*Employee map{

  "Employee": ($) mapObject(v,k) -> {
 ---Increment variable value here
    (k):updateReferenceId(v,($$)+1,v)

  }

})}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to explain your use case with an input sample and what you expect as an output.  Then we should be able to provide you with solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can increment values in the accumulator of a reduce operation, and you can then add these to the structured data plan f the output. There are some examples in the MuleSoft DataWeave training course

> `flightsInput reduce (
>       ( flight,
>           acc={
>               american: {price: 0, count: 0},
>               delta: {price: 0, count: 0},
>               united: {price: 0, count: 0}
>           }
>       ) ->
>       flight.airlineName
>       match {
>           case american if(lower(american) contains "amer") ->
>               acc - "american" ++ american: {
>                   price: acc.american.price + flight.price,
>                   count: acc."american".count + 1
>           }
>           case delta if(lower(delta) contains "del") ->
>               acc - "delta" ++ delta: {
>                   price: acc.delta.price + flight.price,
>                   count: acc."delta".count + 1
>               }
>           case united if(lower(united) contains "uni") ->
>               acc - "united" ++ united: {
>                   price: acc.united.price + flight.price,
>                 count: acc."united".count + 1
>               }
>           else -> acc
>       }
>   )`

This creates a data structure with the three different key performance indicators:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As usual in functional languages, like DataWeave, [you can not increment a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922134/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-functional-programming). You can return an incremented value from an expression instead. For example you could do a recursive function that return its input incremented by one. Just assume that variables are immutable in DataWeave.

You should first try to think what problem are you trying to solve, why do you really need to increment that variable and why the index of mapObject() would not fit that need.